# Create drop down menu of Posts from Category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, navigation, wp-list-categories

I'm working on this site [www.annapogossova.com](http://www.annapogossova.com) for a friend.

Currently the menu navigation is running through Pages i've created each gallery in.

When it comes time to expand the site - I want it to be fairly dynamic so that each gallery page/post is added to the drop down menu automatically and she doesn't have to edit the nav.php file in order to get them to show correctly.

Surely there is a work around for this? I may have gone about the setup the wrong way - should I have created the galleries as Posts and not Pages?

If Pages are alright - is there a way to work the menu better so that it lists the Pages under each category?

I feel it would work a lot better in the future if all the galleries were Posts in a category??

So the Wordpress Structure is currently:

Nav text is html > ul & li creates nav list pages manually > Page (each new gallery) with an iframe

This is what the nav.php currently looks like

-Edit, I can't post more than 1 link.. sorry

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? Version 3 has a rewritten menu system, and is much more easily customisable, after a merge with the WooThemes system: http://wordpress.org/news/2010/02/menus-merge-patch-sprint/

Comment: Ah great! I'll update and check it out on the weekend!
WordPress 2.9.2. i'm on. 

I just watched the tutorial/intro video on the woothemes website - it looks super easy to create page and sub page menu items - but can you create a sub sub page like Pat has listed my structure to be below? 

Surely yes! I'll update and check it anywho. I'll let you all know my results!

Comment: Great, so i've got 3.0 installed now. 

How would I go about intergrating it into the nav.php ? 

I followed this tutorial http://www.devlounge.net/code/how-to-add-support-for-menus-in-your-wordpress-theme

- But I think i've got my wp_nav_menu wrong.... 


Trying a couple of ways - I'm not sure what it should be- I've structured the content like Pat suggested below - 

      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Photography' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages are fine for what you're doing.  Create a page for each of the top level navigation items.  Next, create sub pages for each sub level (i.e. set their page parent in the admin console).  You'll end up with a page structure that looks like the following:

```
Photography
    Fashion
        Gallery 1
        Gallery 2
        Etc.
    Still Life
        Gallery 1
        Gallery 2
        Etc.
Art & Illustration
    Gallery 1
    Gallery 2
    Etc.
```

Then in your nav.php you can output this all in a `<ul>` structure with the following method:

```
<?php wp_page_menu(); ?>
```

The documentation on the above method [is here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_page_menu).

Comment: Awesome Pat thanks for that!! 

That's the exact thing I need. The MooThemes tool in V3 looks like it will do this automatically for me, here's hoping!

Comment: Great, so i've got 3.0 installed now. 

How would I go about intergrating it into the nav.php ? 

I followed this tutorial http://www.devlounge.net/code/how-to-add-support-for-menus-in-your-wordpress-theme

- But I think i've got my wp_nav_menu wrong.... 


Trying a couple of ways - I'm not sure what it should be- I've structured the content as you suggested.  

      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Photography' ) ); ?>